# Yosemite cert problems

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, osx-yosemite

On Yosemite, I am unable to access multiple pages using Chrome & Safari, but for some reason Firefox always works.  But with this, I'm unable to install certain tools using terminal which is the real problem.  For instance, python.org is unable to load because Safari can't establish a secure connection (same with chrome).  Firefox opens the site just fine, is there any reason behind that?

**Update**

Not behind a proxy.  I'll stick with GitHub.com as an example.  It opens perfect on firefox, no problems.  With Chrome, it will come up without any styling (css/images), just the plain text.  If i open the developer console, there are a bunch of "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE", its all the styling that didn't load.  Same with safari, text show but no styling.

Comment: Can you ellaborate? Installing utilities in terminal does not go hand in hand with browsers not being able to access sites. Are you behind a proxy? Does firefox have a proxy config. Like I say you need to add more info.

Comment: Updated with Web Browser info, will do terminal after.  I was assuming they were related with similar problems

Comment: That error is very similar to network errors from behind the firewall at my office. Do you have software firewall enabled

Comment: Actually off.  Using McAfee but the firewall has been off the whole time

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like your network settings are bad. These things are supposed to work. Create a new network profile and disable mcafee. Stack overflow is not really for this type of issue. A Mac forum would be better to get help. Come back once you've got the browser working. Good luck.